# Declaration is deemed incompatibile

Tags: c++, templates, generics, abstract-class, virtual

Straight to the point:

1. I have an abstract class called `Chart<IType>` with child `CandlestickChart<CandlestickChartItem>` etc.
2. ... an abstract class called `ChartItem` with child `CandlestickChartItem` etc.
3. ... an abstract class called `ChartSelection` with child `CandlestickChartSelection` etc.

Relevant piece of code:

```
/* --- CHARTS --- */
template <typename IType>
class Chart {
    ...
    typedef std::vector<IType> ChartData;
}

class CandlestickChart :
    public Chart<CandlestickChartItem> { }

/* --- CHART SELECTIONS --- */
template <typename ChartType>
class ChartSelection {
    ...
    virtual ChartType::ChartData::const_iterator findStart() = 0;
};

class CandlestickChartSelection : public ChartSelection<CandlestickChart> {
    ...
    CandlestickChart::ChartData::const_iterator findStart() override;
};
```

How compiler feels about this:

```
Error   C2253   'ChartSelection<CandlestickChart>::findStart':
    pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
Error   C3668   'CandlestickChartSelection::findStart':
    method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
```

**TL;DR:** Why does my compiler think that the method `findStart` in the child class is different from the virtual function in the parent class?
Is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing uninstalling MSVC and installing MinGW might be a bit un-simple

Comment: @tobi303 Ok :) But are they really distinct? `ChartType::ChartData::const_iterator` and `ChartType::ChartData::const_iterator` look the same to me.

Comment: @PasserBy, sorry, I don't understand - is this a MSVC specific thing?

Comment: @user35443 you really miss `typename`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb where?

Comment: @user35443 Apparently, yes. MSVC has some of the best error messages. [Check this](http://cpp.sh/9gel3)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb got it, thank you :) You can post it as an answer.  Just, why is the typename there necessary?

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ok, I see you were kidding me :P The g++ error message says it all :D